# Clarification about notation

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am confused with the notation $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x)$. I understand that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ is the ring of polynomials in two variables over $\mathbb{Q}$. So $(x)$ has to be an ideal. Could anyone explain what $(x)$ means? Thank you

Comment: $(x)$ is the principal ideal generated by $x$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So I thought. Does that mean $(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[x]$?

Comment: @AloysiusGodinho No. Note that $1\notin (x)$ and $xy\in (x)$. We have $(x)=x\cdot \Bbb Q[x,y]$. But $\Bbb Q[x,y]/(x)$ is very isomorphic to $\Bbb Q[y]$.

Comment: @ HagenvonEitzen Got it.

Answer (score 2):

If $R$ is a ring and $a \in R$, then $(a)$ denotes the [principal ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal) generated by $a$, i.e. the smallest two-sided ideal which contains $a$.

Answer (score 1):

$(x)$ is the principle ideal generated by $x$, so the polynomials which are a multiple of $x$.

It is important to note that $F[x]$ is a PID when $F$ is a field.